The selenium driver server has unexpectedly died on Chrome Headless
Getting this WebDriverException: The driver server has unexpectedly died! when running regression pack on headless chrome on linux.
WebDriverException: The driver server has unexpectedly died!<br/>
Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'<br/>
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1160.114.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.22'<br/>
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver<br/>
Command: [5948842c582bf23e60d520f14c5fd9a8, getWindowHandles {}]<br/>
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 124.0.6367.60, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 124.0.6367.91 (51df0e5e17a8..., userDataDir: null}, fedcm:accounts: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(direct), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}<br/>
Session ID: 5948842c582bf23e60d520f14c5fd9a8, UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused, ConnectException: Connection refused]

chrome browser - 124.0.6367.60 selenium-version- 4.16.1
Due to this error browser gets close and not able to perform any interaction on UI.
